# python array reference not removing element from the array

Tags: python, arrays, list, reference

I was adding and removing elements to an array reference within a method, and i found that though the elements were getting added to the array in reference but it was not getting removed.

```
def check(arr):
    arr.append(1)
    arr = arr[:-1]

arr = [1]
check(arr)
print(arr)
```

gives the output `[1, 1]` I want to know why `arr = arr[:-1]` not removing from the referenced array

EDIT: a lot of people are posting the correct solution, I am not looking for a solution, instead an explanation of why and how python creates a local variable instead of overwriting the global scope and how does it maintain the two by the same name !

Comment: `arr = arr[:-1]` This creates a _new_ local variable named `arr`.  It does not affect the original argument.

Comment: `arr[:] = arr[:-1]` or *(for this particular case)* `del arr[-1]`

Comment: You don't have an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). Those two are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've already pointed in [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70723167/10824407#comment125026739_70723167) comment, if you need in-place list modification, you can apply [*slice notation*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice):

```py
def check(arr):
    arr.append(1)
    arr[:] = arr[:-1]
```

But in fact this code will just remove last item *(which you have added one line above)*, so you can just use [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement):

```py
def check(arr):
    arr.append(1)
    del arr[-1]
```

Comment: As I have commented on the other answer, can you give an explanation on how python creates a local copy instead of overwriting the global value, how can the local and global be accessed differently ? is this is what is known as the mutable and immutable in python ?

Comment: @isnvi23h4, most of information you can find in official tutorial: [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). Long story short, when you pass list as argument to function, you pass a variable which contains a reference to this list, so changing value of this variable to another reference does not affect content of list which have been originally passed. But when you're using slice notation, it works with list object itself, so modification happens.

Comment: @isnvi23h4, also take a look on this FAQ: [How do I write a function with output parameters (call by reference)?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference). Check [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/10824407) of next question: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/10824407). Similar questions: [python; modifying list inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22054698/10824407), [Python modifying list within function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27264526/10824407)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively it can be done with a global variable:

```
def check_arr():
    global arr
    arr.append(1)
    arr = arr[:-1]

arr = [1]
check_arr()
print(arr)
```

Comment: Although the solution would work, using the global keyword in python should be avoided to keep the global scope as clean as possible. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#global-variable-names or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil.

Comment: @Wrench56 you're right. It's just an example. For educational purposes rather.

Answer (score 0):

You don't return anything. The arr in the function is in local scope, so the global scope arr won't update

```
def check(arr):
    arr.append(1)
    return arr[:-1]

arr = [1]
arr = check(arr)
print(arr)
```

Comment: correct: the func param arr is shadowing the global var arr in this case.